# Singe image navigation with mapped links. Can I opaque each portion of image on hover?

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image we're using for navigation at the top of a website. I used  to set links for each section of the banner. I want to an achieve an opaque effect on hover for each part of the image. Is this possible? Thanks much, Dane.

Answer (score 1):

You could slice the image into seperate images; one for each roll over, the image would still appear to be one image but would have different sections; for the hover you could then either use javascript or have it replace the image with another that appeared opaque

This site shows both the JS method and the CSS method...

http://www.webvamp.co.uk/blog/coding/css-image-rollovers/

just repeat it for each part of the image

Comment: However if you did need specific sections that were not square for example

http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_world.html

then this documentation will help you achieve that

http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/

Comment: I tried using sliced images first and it wasn't formatting correctly on internet explorer. It just feels much more stable this way

Comment: my comment above should help you with the map highlight? Do you have DreamWeaver? that has a handy tool where you can literally draw nodes on the image and it create co-ordinates for the rollover? Also what formatting problems did you have with IE? - they should be easy fixes

Answer (score 1):

You can have a div over each section.  Each div would call a javascript event.  This even can change the div's style.  Something like this:

```
<javascript>
   function changeCss(getId){
     var getDiv = document.getElementById(getId)
     getDiv.className ="myHover"      
   }
</javascript>
<styles>
.plain{
width:150px; 
height:200px; 
position:absolute; 
top:0; 
left:0; 
z-index:1000;
background-color: #666699; 
}
.myHover{
width:150px; 
height:200px; 
position:absolute; 
top:0; 
left:0; 
z-index:1000;
background-color: #666699; 
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
</styles>

    <div onMouseOver="changeCss(this.id)" id="wait" class="plain">
      <img src=""/>                                   
    </div>
```

This is just free hand and has not been tested.  Give it a try and let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: Note:  Filter is for IE.  This is not standard and each browser has its own format:  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp